# jquery getting a specific class from many for a specific element

Tags: jquery

I have the following div element

```
<div id="row_1" class="active_page workorders_edit"></div>
```

And I want to be able to retrieve the class name workorders_edit. In my real case I only have access to the active_page class name

Please check my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bizonbytes/aaAyp/2/) for a better explanation. The end result should populate the id="classname" with only "workorders_edit" and not "active_page workorders_edit"

Thank you.

Comment: Do you just want to check if the element has the class `workorders_edit`?

Comment: This is a horrible idea because any solution introduces a number of specific (and non-obvious) conventions required for your code to not break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/genesis/aaAyp/3/

```
var classname = $('.active_page').attr('class').split(' ')[1];
```

**Note:** only works when active_page class is first in the class attribute, and workorders_edit is the next class in the class attribute... any variation of this will break

Comment: **Note**: only works when `active_page` class is first in the class attribute, and `workorders_edit` is the next class in the class attribute...  any variation of this will break.

Comment: Works perfectly for my need.  Thank for sharing a part of your brain.

Answer (score 0):

This would work for your specific scenario -

```
$('#classname').text(classname.split(' ')[1]);
```

But it will only work while 'workorders_edit' is the second class name in a list of classes, if a new class was added to the start of the list of classes linked to your div it would no longer work.

Comment: **Note**: only works when `active_page` class is first in the class attribute, and `workorders_edit` is the next class in the class attribute...  any variation of this will break.